# Wanna make this list, and show infos about the person, all this by choosing the number, and give option to add names and infos

Tags: python

The error is:
File "main.py", line 37
    print (namelist [10])
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I basicly want to solve the problem and be able to create a namelist with infos that the input choose.

```
namelist = []
print ("Names List: ")
print ("0- Felipe")
print ("1- Antonio")
print ("2- Gustavo")
print ("3- Eric ")
print ("4- Callou")
print ("5- Joaquim ")
print ("6- Pedro")
print ("7- Lucas")
print ("8- Gabriel")
print ("9- Rodrigo")
namelist.append("Name: Felipe ; Age: 16; Class: 11c1") #namelist[0]
namelist.append("Name: Antonio  ; Age; 16; Class: 11c1") #namelist[1]
namelist.append("Name: Gustavo ; Age: 16; Class: 11c1") #namelist[2]
namelist.append("Name: Eric ; Age: 16; Class: 11c1") #namelist[3]
namelist.append("Name: Callou; Age: 16; Class: 11c1") #namelist[4]
namelist.append("Name: Joaquim ; Age: 17; Class: 11c1") #namelist[5]
namelist.append("Name: Pedro ; Age: 16; Class: 10c1") #namelist[6]
namelist.append("Name: Lucas; Age: 13; Class: 7c1") #namelist[7]
namelist.append("Name: Gabriel ; Age: 13; Class: 7c2") #namelist[8]
namelist.append("Name: Rodrigo ; Age: 17; Turma: 12c2") #namelist[9]

r = (input ("Is your on the list?: "))

if (r.upper() == "YES", "SIM", "JA"):
     n = (int (input("What's your number?: ")))
     nameindex = n
     print (namelist[nameindex])
else:
    nn = input ("What's your name?: ")
    na = int (input ("What's your age?: "))
    nc = input ("What's your class?: ")
    namelist.append ("Name: {} ; Age: {}; Class: {}".format("nn", "na", "nc") #namelist[10]
    print (namelist[10])
```

Comment: `input` returns a string; even if you enter a number, it will return the string representation of that number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this line  `n = (input ("What's your number?: "))` you are taking user input,by default  the `input()` method takes user input as string form so you need to type cast the user input into integer if you want to use this number as an index of the list.

To type cast input as integer you have to do something like that:

```
n = int(input ("What's your number?: "))
```

Otherwise it will raises an error like this:

```
File "main.py", line 29, in print (namelist[nameindex]) TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Thank you, i actually just actualized the code, and ask another thing lol

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (r.upper() == "YES"):
    n = input ("What's your number?: ")
    print(namelist[int(n)])
```

because with `input()` method you get an string, so you have to parse into integer for index your list

Comment: That helped me, thanks. I just actually actualized the post and ask another question